# How to open intent and add value android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have trouble with returning a value to another intent in android.
This is my situation:
I have Activity A, which is opened when I start my application.
When I click on a button I start Activity B.
In activity B I fill in a EditText and return a string.
Then I click on a button in activity B to return to activity A.
I don't know what method I should use in activity A to use the value I get returned from activity B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of situation fits good for `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityForResult`. When you press on the button, instead of calling `startActivity` you call `startActivityForResult` in order to start `ActivityB`. In `ActivityB` when you click on the button, you have to fill up an Intent with the values you want to return to ActivityA and, in order, call `setResult(result, Intent)` and `finish()`. The `onActivityResult` of `ActivityA` will receive the intent with your data

[Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: You beat me and yours was more detailed :P. So hope you don't mind me adding a link

Answer (score 0):

You should start activity B by calling startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and on Activity B, in your exit button click listener, setResult() results to pass to Activity A.

You can handle the result by overriding onActivityResult() method in Activity A

Check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/activity.html
Search for "Starting Activities and Getting Results"